# How can I stop some of my emails from automatically showing as read before I view it?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

How can I stop some of my messages in my inbox from automatically showing as read before I view it?

In some cases they will show as unread for sometime and also automatically change read without doing anything. I mean, this will happen with hands completely off the key board/mouse, the email's read state it is changing state on its own accord!

Comment: What add-ons are you using.  What rules have you setup up.  I have never heard of Outlook just marking an email as read unless the email was selected and the message was displayed to the user.

Comment: Are you using the keyboard cursor keys to cycle through your Outlook folders? Because by cycling through still triggers the "mark as read"?

Comment: Did you try a Virus scan? Malware scan? I would still review the add-ons, as per Ramhounds earlier suggestion

Answer (score 1):

In the ribbon click View, Reading Pane -> Options

Change it in here.

Mine are only marked as read when I manually mark as read!

[image]

Comment: yes this is happening, no add-ons, new installation. the same office copy works OK on other computers with i5 but with two i7 new computers different brands this is the case.

Comment: Hang on, how do you know there are no add-ons. Just because you didn't install them doesn't mean they don't exist (Google bloatware)! Also, are you saying your Reading Pane looks the same as my post?

Comment: OK this will happen with hands completely off the key board. Dave it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I understand having the Reading Pane enabled is a security risk due to the potential launching of malicious script/code within the message. I always disable the Reading Pane especially for the Junk E-mail box. I also have Outlook convert all messages to plain text to help address this issue...
"Major Outlook Security Issue: Reading Pane May Automatically Release Trojan Horses, Viruses, Etc."
http://preview.tinyurl.com/9wkmnn6

Comment: there no add-ins, these are two New laptops (a vaio and a ASUS TAICHI) out of the box both with i7 processor, Norton 360 premium, only activate office, set-up outlook and they both display the same issues. The same office activated on a Vaio i5 with no issues.

Comment: Click the View tab, in the Layout section, pull down the Reading Pane menu, click "Off"